# VHDL code not compiling

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, compiler

I'm new to VHDL and I cannot seem to get my code to compile. I've looked over the code to the best of my ability, but I do not see anything wrong with it from my current basic understanding of how it works and I am wondering if anybody could help. The code is supposed to model a NLX1G99 configurable multi-function gate (minus the enable bit)

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity multifun_gate is
port(
        d,c,b,a: in std_logic;
        y: out std_logic
    );
end multifun_gate;

architecture dataflow of multifun_gate is
begin
    y <= (a and not b and not c and not d) or
         (a and b and not c and not d) or
         (not a and b and c and not d) or
         (a and b and c and not d) or
         (not a and not b and not c and d) or
         (not a and b and not c and d) or
         (not a and not b and c and d) or
         (and and not b and c and d);
end dataflow;
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: This is a good example of total incomprehensible and undebugable code. Can't you write what you mean so that people can understand, and the synthesizer can create the gates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second last line:

> (and and not b and c and d);

you have `and` repeated.

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of one error, however, there are still others

Comment: nevermind, that did it. I meant to write "a and not b" rather than "and and not b" and I forgot to replace the and with a after fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the picture in the datasheet, I'd write:

```
sig1 <= a and not c;
sig2 <= b and c;
sig3 <= sig1 or sig2;
y <= d xor sig3;
```

Much easier to check I reckon.

Comment: I would've done that, but that's the way we were asked to do it.

Comment: @audiFanatic: ahh.  Painful! I love it when people are "taught" to fight the tools :)